# Parallelize[] dos not parallelize sum of integrals

Tags: parallelization

I am not sure why this simple command cannot be executed in parallel.

```
Parallelize[ Integrate[ Sin[x], x] 
+  Integrate[ Tan[x], x] ]
```

Error message:

Parallelize::nopar1: [Integral]Sin[x][DifferentialD]x+[Integral]Tan[x][DifferentialD]x cannot be parallelized; proceeding with sequential evaluation.

Comment: I would not call `Integrate` "simple". Take a look at explicit parallelization constructs such as `ParallelMap` to understand what can be easily parallelized and why.

Answer (score 1):

In the help, it mentions `Integrate` explicitly as a possible issues for `Parallelize`: "Expressions that cannot be parallelized are evaluated normally"

[image: snippet from the docs]

So `Integrate` cannot simply be evaluated in parallel.

Comment: Thanks. But suppose I wanted to distribute Integrate on different cores what should I do?

Comment: @QuasarSupernova you can open another .nb file and do the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

A single `Integrate` evaluation can only use a single core.

If you want to run several independent `Integrate`s in parallel, then add up their results, use

```
Plus @@ Parallelize[{Integrate[ Sin[x], x], Integrate[ Tan[x], x]}]
```